# Compiled queries or not

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Hey there!
Earlier today I came across a new term "compiled queries" in linq2entity and found out what it was used for, however I still wonder whether there are any drawbacks since its never used anywhere? (atleast in the web dev world)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think it is never used anywhere?

Comment: Never used in the web dev world? You must have missed [this](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-pre-compiled-linq-to-entities-queries-in-web-apps-and-services/).

Answer (score 0):

compiled queries are just a little bit faster than normal queries. they are often used when one query needs to executed repetitively. however, there is no huge difference in performance. in fact, stack-overflow.com is built using normal linq queries and as you can see the performance is great

Comment: Yes but Stackoverflow is using L2S that's substantially faster than EF.

Comment: i didn't know about L2S. there's a video on channel9 on msdn.microsoft.com for ScottAllen who talks about the subject of compiled queries and mentions stack-overflow as an example of using linq efficiently

Comment: If you'd like to read a little more about Stack Overflow and compiled LINQ to SQL queries, Jeff blogged about it at http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/compiled-or-bust.html

Comment: Does that mean I should compile my queries or not in "every-day" projects? According to the test results between not-compiled and compiled queries, the compiled queries almost half the time compared to the not-compiled one..

Comment: That's all wrong. They're are big performance gains to be had with compiled queries. Also +1 to everyone that pointed out that SO is using L2S and not L2E.